# Node JS on Boot

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I am running a raspberry pi B+ with the intentions of running a node js app on boot.

I am using the command `su pi -c 'node /home/pi/bartender_main/app.js < /dev/null &'`
in my /etc/rc.local file. 
When it boots up it act like it work and give me my indication that it is ready, but shortly is says board closing and it quits the app.
Does anyone have any ideas.
Thanks

Comment: Who or what says "board closing"? Which system are you running your RPi?

Comment: The `&` makes that command run in the background, which may let its parent process terminate earlier than wanted. Try it without the `&`, and make sure it is the last command in the script.

Comment: I have raspbian, I am running node JS and I am communicating to a Arduino via the Johnny-Five Node Package. When I mean board closing it is on the terminal of the RPI as it is booting.

Comment: @phssthpok I tried it without the & and nothing. Whats odd is when I manually execute the program it runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Board Closing` message is printed when the Johnny-Five repl [reaches the end of its standard input](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/2539bebc33acb624997e23fe72d1729573d859d8/lib/repl.js#L79) or its process [receives a SIGINT](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/2539bebc33acb624997e23fe72d1729573d859d8/lib/board.js#L409).

Directing `/dev/null` to stdin causes that end of input, so this is likely what is happening. (Also, init scripts are more likely to be killed by SIGTERM or SIGHUP.) Without seeing the internals of `app.js`, it is hard to say what it is trying to do, but it is probably something like [this](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/master/docs/repl.md). You could keep it alive past the initial launch by not ending stdin:

```
su pi -c 'node /home/pi/bartender_main/app.js'
```